# Method overloading and overridding

Tags: oop

Method overloading is binding during compile time and overriding occurred during run time.is it possible for method overriding to occur at compile time?? And is there any process so we can override method at compile time??

Comment: The specifics may vary between specific languages, but typically method overriding *does* happen at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Method Overriding and method overloading are different concept one happens at run time and another one happens at compile time. It is not possible to apply Method overriding at compile time because its existence comes when the particular method is called. Or you can say that run time, calling virtual methods. compile time, calling any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Method Overloading means loading of the same data type or the same number of parameters is going to pass into that method. It will overload the method with different types of arguments.

my_method_area(*args)
my_method_area(radius, center)
my_method_area(length, bredth)

Method Overriding it will override the same method with the same number of parameters but calling from another function.
classA():
method1(length, height, breadth)
classB():
method1(length, height, breadth)